# Anti-forgery from opayo iframe token meant for a different claims based user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nopcommerce, antiforgerytoken

Using Nop Commerce and Opayo as a payment provider, I'm getting the error 'Anti-forgery token meant for a different claims based user' when checking out as a logged in user. Using a guest account is fine.

We pass a redirect URL to Opayo and then a page is loaded with a form. The action is on the form is to a POST method which fails the Antiforgery validation.

The cookie options SameSite is set to none, which allowed the guest checkout to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.